# Google Earth suddently won't start on Windows 10

Tags: google-earth

I have Windows 10 (version 1803) and have used Google Earth for over a year.

All of a sudden yesterday, it simply won't start. I double-click on the icon but nothing happens.

- I went into `C:\program files\Google\Google Earth Pro\client` and double-clicked on it, but same thing.
- I deinstalled and reinstalled it, but same thing.
- I tried to start it in as Administrator, but same thing.

I've had no hardware changes on the machine and did not install any updates for weeks. I notice no other problems with any other programs.

**How can I get Google Earth to work again?**

Comment: I had several items break with the updates from a couple weeks ago. After a bit of troubleshooting and uninstalling one of the updates, I was able to get things to work. YMMV, and it sounds like you looked into it, but the "recently" is subjective. Otherwise, I don't have anything to offer.

Comment: Thanks, I changed "recently" to "did not install any updates for weeks" and Google Earth stopped working yesterday.